# How do I get the equivalent path given by redirect_to in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, path

`redirect_to` allows you to use the controller, action and id variables to generate a URL to redirect to. Is there an equivalent method just to get the URL?

Currently I'm using this code to get the path of a student from the students controller with the dashboard action, but I have to manually append the action on the end:

```
student_path(:controller => 'students', :id => @controller.current_student.id)+'/dashboard'
```

Comment: You should have a dedicated named route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :students do
  member do
    get 'dashboard'
  end
end
```

This will give each student their own dashboard path.  Then your path will be `dashboard_student_path(:student)`

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me to where the documentation for the underlying method of `dashboard_student_path` is?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a matcher in your routes file something like this.

```
match '/students/:id/dashboard' => 'students#dashboard', :as => 'dashboard'
```

This will then give you path and url named routes as `dashboard_path` and `dashboard_url`

Subsequently, when you call this you can just pass in a student object `dashboard_path my_student`